# Python - tkinter widgets failing to work , moreover I don't understand the traceback i get

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have this error with tkinter widgets inside of one of my classes . The thing I don't understand is really what the error is trying to tell me and where I have gone wrong . Here is the error I receive whenever I run the code:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/ttk.py", line 553, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2142, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
    _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-command"
```

Here is the code :

```
 def play():
        while True:
            if self.questions_asked == 20:
                answer_label = ttk.Label(self , text="That's the end of the quiz. Your score for that round was {}! ")
                answer_label.pack()
                break
            self.random_question = random.randint(0,39)

            while not self.random_question in self.questions:
                self.random_question = random.randint(0,39)

            question_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Question {} : {}".format(i , self.questions[self.random_question]))
            question_label.pack()

            check_answer = ttk.Button(self, text="Check your answer.", command=lambda:check())
            check_answer.pack()

            remove_key(self.random_question, self.questions)
            remove_key(self.random_question, self.answers)
            self.questions_asked +=1

        def check():

            get_user_entry = entry_box.get()
            if get_user_entry == None:
                question_label = tkinter.Label(self, text="Please put an answer into the entry box.")
                question_label.pack()

            if get_user_entry == "end":
                question_label = tkinter.Label(self, text="Thanks for playing! ")
                question_label.pack()
                lambda: shown_frame.show_frame(OpeningFrame)

            else:
                verify_answer(get_user_entry, self.random_question, self.questions)
                if verify_answer == True:
                    answer_label = ttk.Label(self, text="You got it correct !")
                    answer_label.pack()
                else:
                    answer_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Sorry the answer was {}".format(self.answers[self.random_question]))
                    answer_label.pack()


    overhead_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Welcome to the Quiz page. Click the button below to start.")
    overhead_label.pack()

    entry_box = tkinter.Entry(self)
    entry_box.pack()

    start_quiz = ttk.Button(self, text="Start the quiz.", command=play())
    start_quiz.pack()


    home_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go back to home page", command=lambda: shown_frame.show_frame(OpeningFrame))
    home_button.pack(pady=15, padx=15)
```

Comment: When you assign the command to your `start_quiz` button, assign the **callable** `play`, instead of calling it (`play()`) when you assign it.  Eg: `..., command=play)`

Comment: Your code cannot be run the way it is, so I cannot see the error. Neither the import nor the class containing the play function are there. You should post the smallest runnable code that triggers the error.

Comment: always show FULL error message (Traceback). You show only part of message and I don't see which line in your code makes problem. Some widgets doesn't have `command=` - but you use `command=` with this type of widget - and this is your error message.

Comment: BTW: `command=` (and `bind()`) expects **callback** - it means function name without `()` and arguments - i.e `comman=play` or `command=check` . You can use `lambda` if you have to assign function with argument - ie. `command=lambda:shown_frame.show_frame(OpeningFrame)`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show **full** error message (Traceback) - it should show line in your code which makes problem.

I guess you use `command=` with widget which doesn't have this option - and this is your error message.

Comment: No that was the full traceback . I double checked it and it didn't include any line number .

Comment: Yeh that was it , i used command on a label widget ... thank you